# Ctypes executes callback function, then incorrectly calls the dll again

Tags: python, dll, callback, nasm, ctypes

I wrote a dll in NASM to be called from Python using ctypes.  I created a short Python callback program within my ctypes wrapper:

```
def LibraryCall(a):
    b = math.ceil(a)
    return b
```

I know the dll calls the callback function because when I step through the ctypes wrapper, the cursor jumps to the callback function, performs the callback, and returns to call the dll again, which seems to be the problem.

The Python ctypes code is:

```
def SimpleTestFunction_asm(X):

    Input_Length_Array = []
    Input_Length_Array.append(len(X))

    CA_X = (ctypes.c_double * len(X))(*X)

    length_array_out = (ctypes.c_double * len(Input_Length_Array))  (*Input_Length_Array)

    hDLL = ctypes.WinDLL    ("C:/Test_Projects/SimpleTestFunction/SimpleTestFunction.dll")
    CallName = hDLL.Main_Entry_fn
    CallName.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER (ctypes.c_double),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),ctypes.POINTER    (ctypes.c_longlong)]
    CallName.restype = ctypes.c_int64

    #__________
    #The callback function

    LibraryCB = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double)

    def LibraryCall(a): #CALLBACK FUNCTION IN PYTHON
        b = math.ceil(a)
        return b

    lib_call = LibraryCB(LibraryCall)
lib_call = ctypes.cast(lib_call,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_longlong))

    #__________

    ret_ptr = CallName(CA_X, length_array_out, lib_call) ; CALL TO DLL

    a = ret_ptr[:2]
    n0 = ctypes.cast(a[0],ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
    n0_size = int(a[0+1] / 8)
    x0 = n0[:n0_size]
```

When I step through the program, what happens now is that the cursor jumps from the line marked "CALL TO DLL" to the line marked "CALLBACK FUNCTION IN PYTHON."  It executes the Python callback program correctly, then the cursor jumps back to the line marked "CALL TO DLL" at which point it crashes with no error message.  It seems like it returns back to call the DLL again, but I want it to execute the callback function and return the result back to the already-called DLL.

Here is the simple NASM test code:

```
; Header Section
[BITS 64]

[default rel]

export Main_Entry_fn
export FreeMem_fn

extern malloc, realloc, free

section .data align=16
[DATA SECTION OMITTED FOR BREVITY]

section .text

SimpleTestFunction_fn:
xor rcx,rcx
mov [loop_counter_401],rcx
label_401:
lea rdi,[rel X_ptr]
mov rbp,qword [rdi] ; Pointer
mov rcx,[loop_counter_401]
mov rax,[X_length]
cmp rcx,rax
jge exit_label_for_SimpleTestFunction_fn
movsd xmm0,qword[rbp+rcx]
movsd [x_var],xmm0

;______

movsd xmm1,[const_40]
mulsd xmm0,xmm1
movsd [a],xmm0

movsd xmm0,[a]
call [CB_Pointer] ; THIS IS THE CALL TO THE CALLBACK FUNCTION
movsd [b],xmm0

ret

;__________
;Free the memory

FreeMem_fn:

;The pointer is passed back in rcx (of course)

sub rsp,40
call free
add rsp,40
ret

; __________
; Main Entry

Main_Entry_fn:
push rdi
push rbp
mov [X_ptr],rcx
mov [data_master_ptr],rdx
mov [CB_Pointer],r8
; Now assign lengths
lea rdi,[data_master_ptr]
mov rbp,[rdi]
xor rcx,rcx
movsd xmm0,qword[rbp+rcx]
cvttsd2si rax,xmm0
mov [X_length],rax
add rcx,8
; __________
; malloc for dynamic arrays
lea rdi,[data_master_ptr]
mov rbp,[rdi]
movsd xmm0,qword[rbp]
cvttsd2si rax,xmm0
mov [initial_dynamic_length],rax
mov rcx,qword[initial_dynamic_length] ; Initial size
xor rax,rax
sub rsp,40
call malloc
mov qword [collect_ptr],rax
add rsp,40
mov rax,[initial_dynamic_length]
mov [collect_length],rax
; __________
call SimpleTestFunction_fn
exit_label_for_Main_Entry_fn:
pop rbp
pop rdi
ret
```

I have already confirmed that the problem is not in the dll, because it returns to Python at the line where it calls the callback function, but it does not return a value to the dll after it executes the callback function; instead, it calls the dll again.

So to sum it up, after the call to the callback function, ctypes returns to call the dll again, which is not what I want.

Thanks very much for an ideas on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this question is that the return must be in parentheses: return (b).  With that, it works correctly.

However, there is now a problem with ctypes crashing on exit.  I posted that as a separate question at [Python ctypes callback crashes on exit with exception code c0000005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885754/python-ctypes-callback-crashes-on-exit-with-exception-code-c0000005).

Thanks.